# Button keeps on disappearing when clicked to call a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function remove() {
debugger;
alert('sahd');
}
```

```html
<div style="padding-top:8px;padding-left:5px;border:solid;border-color:black;border-width:thin;width:350px;height:75px;" id="divv">
    <label>Abcd1</label>
    <input type="button" onclick="remove(); return false;" />
    <label>Abcd1</label>
    <input type="button" onclick="remove(); return false;" />
    <label>Abcd1</label>
    <input type="button" onclick="remove(); return false;" />
    </div>
```

```
    //javascript code
function remove() {
debugger;
alert('sahd');
}
```

above is my html code and javascript function. when i click on the buttons, they keep on disappearing.

Please help

Comment: `debugger;` ? `remove()` itself is a JavaScript function to remove the element.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_remove.asp Using the remove() function on a DOM element will effectively remove it. please override the function or rename it, like suggested below by T.J. Crowder

Comment: @briosheje never trust w3schools; it's full of mistakes.

Comment: @user29938990 Further reading of `remove()` : http://red-team-design.com/removing-an-element-with-plain-javascript-remove-method/

Comment: @Raptor: I don't trust it aswell, but it is surprisingly right this time: http://jsfiddle.net/b0d5Lp60/ (I've tested it on a fiddle before posting)

Answer (score 2):

It's an unfortunate naming thing. If you change your function name to `foo` (or whatever) rather than `remove`, it'll stop happening (see below).

The environment that `onXyz` handlers run in is a complex one, and ***one*** of the complexities is that your `onXyz` code effectively runs within a `with` statement using the element:

```
with (theElement) {
    // your code
}
```

There's more to it than that, but that's one aspect of it.

On modern browsers, elements have a `remove` method that removes them from the DOM. So that's what gets called instead of your *global* `remove` function.

Example using `foo` instead, so it's not the same name as the element's `remove` method:

```js
function foo() {
    alert('sahd');
}
```

```html
<div style="padding-top:8px;padding-left:5px;border:solid;border-color:black;border-width:thin;width:350px;height:75px;" id="divv">
    <label>Abcd1</label>
    <input type="button" onclick="foo(); return false;" />
    <label>Abcd1</label>
    <input type="button" onclick="foo(); return false;" />
    <label>Abcd1</label>
    <input type="button" onclick="foo(); return false;" />
    </div>
```

---

This is one of many reasons to use modern event handling techniques rather than `onXyz` handlers. Another is that with `onXyz` handlers, your functions have to be globals, but the global namespace is already **way** too crowded and you can end up with unfortunate conflicts. With modern techniques (`addEventListener`, or `attachEvent` on IE8 and below), you're in much more control of the environment in which your handlers run, and they don't have to be globals.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are calling `remove()` javascript function.

Reference : [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_remove.asp)

Just Change `function remove()`  to `function xyz()` like

```js
function xyz() {
debugger;
alert('sahd');
}
```

```html
<div style="padding-top:8px;padding-left:5px;border:solid;border-color:black;border-width:thin;width:350px;height:75px;" id="divv">
    <label>Abcd1</label>
    <input type="button" onclick="xyz(); return false;" />
    <label>Abcd1</label>
    <input type="button" onclick="xyz(); return false;" />
    <label>Abcd1</label>
    <input type="button" onclick="xyz(); return false;" />
    </div>
```

Comment: saheb.. That worked.. awesome.. Can you please tell me how can I delete the previous label when I click the button. If i click the 1st button, the first label should be deleted.

Comment: Didn't get you? What you want to delete? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Please don't quote w3schools links; most of them are misleading. Read http://w3fools.com

Comment: @GaneshSalunkhe : if you see I have 3 labels and 3 buttons. If i click on 1st button, then the Abcd1 label should get delete. This is my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use anchor tag and use css to give design as a button. You just need to do as below

```
 <a href="javascript:remove()" id="my button" >test</a>
```

This could also be an alternative.

Hope this will help.